# How add devise link(google_auth button) on main page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I created auth with devise gem and all works good but i want add google-auth button on main page how should i do it?

I tried just adding it to the main page, but it uses the devise private method so i get an error
"undefined local variable or method `resource_class'".

[link from views/shared/_links.html.erb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb6Pp.png)

My production: https://taras-rails-app.fly.dev

If you need more code you can find it on my github: https://github.com/Tarasukk/Web

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please do not use screenshots of code - **ever**. They are not searchable, copyable and you're making it harder for people that are willing to help you.  Include the relevant code as text. In the case of Devise `resource_class` is just the model class that you have configured via the the routes. So if you have  `devise_for :users` then the resource_class is `User` and the resource_name is `:user`. This code is very modular and is made to work with any class and a whole list of providers - so it's not actually what you need to link to a single provider.

Comment: You can see the routes in your application by running `rails routes`. Among them should be the routes created by omniauth.

Comment: @max Thank you for solving the problem and for the advice